# Match not prefix namespace in xslt template

Tags: xslt

I have the XML which I need to sort by Type tag. This XML also has the ContractSummary tag with a namespace. I've tried to find the ContractSummary tag by adding namespace-uri()='ContractSummary' to the template but it doesn't work.
Also, it is not allowed to change xsl:stylesheet tag because it is hardcoded.

Please help me to change my template to work with namespaces in the ContractSummary tag.

XSLT version in 2.0.

```
<ContractSummary xmlns="ContractSummary" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="ContractSummary schema.xsd">
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product2</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
</Offerings>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product1</Type>
    <Name Language="ZFR">Enlvement</Name>
</Offerings> </ContractSummary>
```

XSLT template:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='ContractSummary' and namespace-uri()='ContractSummary' ]"> 
<xsl:copy>   
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Offerings">
    <xsl:sort select="Type"  />  
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>   </xsl:template>
```

As result I have:

```
<ContractSummary xmlns="ContractSummary" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></ContractSummary>
```

I need xml:

```
<ContractSummary xmlns="ContractSummary" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product1</Type>
    <Name Language="ZFR">Enlvement</Name>
</Offerings>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product2</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
</Offerings></ContractSummary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Offerings">
```

does not do anything because `Offerings`  is in a namespace too (and so is `Type`). Also, there is no need to use a hack like `*[local-name()='ContractSummary'`.

Properly, you would declare a default namespace in the `xsL;stylesheet` start-tag. You say you are not allowed to change it (why?) so try:

```
<xsl:template match="ContractSummary" xpath-default-namespace="ContractSummary"> 
    <xsl:copy>   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Offerings">
            <xsl:sort select="Type"  />  
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, this assumes you also have a template that would match `Offerings`.

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniV8